# Highlight the selected value in Typescript (Angular)

Tags: typescript

I have the certain values in the Display Box. If I select one value, after selecting that particular value, the row gets highlighted(denotes the user that the value is selected). If again user, selects the other value, the other value also gets highlighted. But My Question, How can we remove the highlight for the previous value.

HTML

```
       <div *ngFor="let cars of carsData">
         <p  id="categoryTag{{cars.carId}}" class="listheight" (click)="ListBrands(cars.carId,cars.carsTitle)">BMW</p>
         <p  id="categoryTag{{cars.carId}}" class="listheight" (click)="ListBrands(cars.carId,cars.carsTitle)">Maruthi Suzuki</p>
         <p  id="categoryTag{{cars.carId}}" class="listheight" (click)="ListBrands(cars.carId,cars.carsTitle)">Volvo</p>
         <p  id="categoryTag{{cars.carId}}" class="listheight" (click)="ListBrands(cars.carId,cars.carsTitle)">Benz</p>
         <p  id="categoryTag{{cars.carId}}" class="listheight" (click)="ListBrands(cars.carId,cars.carsTitle)">Audi</p>
       </div>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
       ListBrands(carId,carTitle){
       this.carIDvalue = carId;
       this.CarHeader = carTitle;
       document.getElementById("categoryTag"+carId).style.background="#0098b2";   
       document.getElementById("categoryTag"+carId).style.color="#fff";   
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since cardIDvalue holds the id of previously highlighted element, you could try removing the background color for that element first and then do the changes for the newly selected one.

```
ListBrands(carId,carTitle){
  // change style of previously selected value
  document.getElementById("categoryTag"+this.carIDvalue).style.background="#fff";   
  document.getElementById("categoryTag"+this.carIDvalue).style.color="#000";
   
  this.carIDvalue = carId;
  this.CarHeader = carTitle;
  document.getElementById("categoryTag"+carId).style.background="#0098b2";   
  document.getElementById("categoryTag"+carId).style.color="#fff";   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to handle that via CSS class and only identifying who is the selected element.
Easier to maintain and to style that later.

```
ListBrands(carId,carTitle){
   this.carIDvalue = carId;
   this.CarHeader = carTitle;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let cars of carsData">
         <p  id="categoryTag{{cars.carId}}" [ngClass]="{'listheight':true, 'selected': cardIDvalue === cars.carId}" (click)="ListBrands(cars.carId,cars.carsTitle)">BMW</p>
</div>
```

```css
.selected {
    background: #0098b2
    color: "#ffff"
}
```

Also there is something weird at your `ngFor`. I would expect to see a single line inside the loop, instead you are repeating all the possibilities in it.
It also generates invalid HTML (since you have several elements with the same id)

Answer (score 0):

```js
ListBrands(carId, carTitle) {
  this.carIDvalue = carId;
  this.CarHeader = carTitle;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let cars of carsData">
         <p  id="categoryTag{{cars.carId}}" [ngClass]="(carIDvalue==cars.carId)?'highlight':'not-highlight'" (click)="ListBrands(cars.carId,cars.carsTitle)">{{cars.carsTitle}}</p>
</div>
```